# PHP doesn't recognise an Object in my pattern MVC

Tags: php, object, model-view-controller, runtime-error

I hope you could help me with this problem:

I tried to implement a pattern MVC in php + HTML5 + css. Now, apart the model, i have a problem when i try to instantiate an PHP object in one of my Controller.

In particular, i have to print the data about the authenticated user, stored in one object, $userObject, that i tried to instantiate with the DataBase data.

So I declared it, i initialized it at Null and, after, i tried to instantiate it with his constructor.

After, when i try to use it, PHP tells me: " Call to a member function getEmail() **on a non-object** in C:\Users\1USER\Documents\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\ammPHP\PHP\Controller\LoginController.php on line 99"

I show you the extract of codes about the problems:

```
 /**the function handle_input rappresent the core of my controller, that popolates the variables of the master.PHP to make a virtual page and to visualize the user's profile.**/

    private function handle_input(&$request, &$session)
    {
        $userObject = null;
        $mysqli = new mysqli(); 


    //login module: it verify the user data and modify the $_SESSION's array
    //It makes also an object of class AuthenticatedUser that full with the database Data about the logged user.

        if(isset($request["userid"]) && isset($request["password"]))
        {   
            if($this->login($request["userid"], $request["password"]))
            {   
                $session["loggedIn"] = true;    

                $mysqli->connect("localhost", "root", "password", "database"); 
                $userid = $request["userid"]; 
                $password = $request["password"];

                $query = "SELECT * FROM loggeduser WHERE (userID = '$userid') AND (passwd = '$password');";

                $result = $mysqli->query($query);
                //errors checking salted

                while($user = $result->fetch_object())
                {
                    $userObject = new AuthenticatedUser($userid, $password, $user -> email, $user -> nome, $user -> cognome, $user -> dataNascita, $user -> città, $user -> CAP, $user -> indirizzo, $user -> cellulare);

                  }

    }//user is logged-in
    else if(isset($request["logout"]))
    {   
        $this->logout();    
    }


    //Master.php dedicated module: It verify that user is logged-in, then initialize 
    //the variables to popolate the master PHP and to make the virtual page of the profile's user.

    if(isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) && $_SESSION[ "loggedIn"]) 
    {
        //CONTROLLO SULLE PAGINA RICHIESTE
        if ($request["subpage"] == "profile") 
        {
            $style = "PHP/view/LoggedUserStyle.php";
            $header = "PHP/view/Header.php";
            $loginFormContent = "PHP/view/loggedUserMenu.php";   //modificato col menù per utenti autenticati
            $slideshow = null;
            $userProfile = "PHP/view/userProfile.php";
            **$user = $userObject -> getEmail(); //Here the problem, PHP tells me that $userObject is not an object! :/**
            $payments = null;
            $orders = null;
            $notFoundContent ="PHP/view/content-not-found.php";
            $footer="PHP/view/footer.php"; 
            include("master.php");
        }
        [...]
     }//closing function handle_input
```

Comment: The while loop isn't being reached. Either because the select returned no rows, or either of the two if statements are failing. Add some `var_dump()`s to find out how far it's getting.

Comment: Do you check if there's actually a result from the query at `//errors checking salted`? Also the `while`-loop is reduntant if you make sure there's precisely one user that matches the information. In that case you could just say `$user = $result->fetch_object(); $userObject = ...`

Comment: You need to check to see if a) the variable is set - isset($userObject), and b) if it is of a type you are expecting - $userObject instanceof AuthenticatedUser.  http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

Comment: Thank you all for the help. The problem was a logical problem beyond the argument that i proposed. I solved, anyway, with a lot of var_dump. Thank you all again :)